# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: wcf

I am getting this error when i am sending more than 500 records to save.so please help me out this is my service

```
    <bindings>

        <wsHttpBinding>


            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMFMReport" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>

            </binding>


    <client>

        <endpoint address="http://localhost:3956/MFMReportService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMFMReport"
            contract="MFMReportService.IMFMReport" name="WSHttpBinding_IMFMReport">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="pkshah@GESCO.COM" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
       </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you tweaked the readerQuotas setting to confirm this not due to some limits on request size.

Comment: You'll need to enable tracing at the server side - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx - to find out what is causing the request to be considered "bad".

Answer (score 0):

That is not your service, that is a client. If you want to pass large dataset to the service you must configure `MaxReceivedMessageSize` on the service - the word Received means that you are configuring message receiver.